# How to retrieve certificates from a pfx file with c#?

Tags: c#, pfx

I've been googling around for half a day looking for a way to read a `.pfx` file and import the certificates into the *certstore*.

So far, I am able to read the `.pfx` file with `X509Certifcate` and able to import one certificate within the `.pfx` file. So far so good, but there are three certificates in the `.pfx` file and when loading the `.pfx` with `X509Certificate`, I am not able to see the other two certificates.

The certificate was exported with

*Personal Information Exchange - PKCS #12 (.PFX)

- Include all certificates in the certification path if possible
- Enable strong protection (requires IE 5.0, NT 4.0 SP4 or above)

Those are the options selected when exporting the certificate(s). I know there are three certificates because I manually go into the *certstore (MMC)* and import it into a personal folder myself.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should be able to get a collection object containing the certs in your *.pfx* file by using the `X509Certificate2Collection` class... here's some C# example code:

```
string certPath = <YOUR PFX FILE PATH>;
string certPass = <YOUR PASSWORD>;

// Create a collection object and populate it using the PFX file
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Then you can iterate over the collection:

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subject is: '{0}'", cert.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine("Issuer is:  '{0}'", cert.Issuer);

    // Import the certificates into X509Store objects
}
```

Depending on the type of certificate (client cert, intermediate CA cert, root CA) you'll need to open the proper cert store (as an `X509Store` object) to import it.

Check out the `X509Store` docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx

And the different members in the `StoreName` enumeration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx

From what I understand, you want to use `StoreName.My` for client certificates that contain a private key, `StoreName.CertificateAuthority` for intermediate CA certs, and `StoreName.Root` for root CA certs.

Comment: Bill, great! I'm seeing all three in the collection. I need to import each one of them in the right store in the Local Computer. StoreName.My, StoreName.Root and StoreName CertificateAuthoriy, just as you mention above. I am able import it into any of the three stores. my next question is, what does the private key do in the pfx file? do i need to do anything with it? i'm new to this stuff. thank you again.

Comment: As far as I know, once a personal certificate with a private key is imported to the My store from a .pfx file, the private key should be ready to use, with no further action needed...for example, client cert authentication with that certificate should work in IE.

Comment: When importing certs for things like mail encryption, etc, you may need them in the CurrentUser stores, but if you import a Root CA cert to CurrentUser, it will pop up a dialog asking "Are you sure you want to trust this?".  The way around this, aparently, is to put the Root CA in the LocalMachine store instead. No popup, and the ICA cert will still work with it.

Comment: When iterating the certs in the .pfx file by using the X509Certificate2Collection, how do we know which of them is the client cert, which the intermediate CA cert (if any), and which the root CA?  Is there a property containing the certificate type?